# Paperclip appends string from :url parameter to request URL instead of directing the request to the specified CloudFront URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, path, paperclip, amazon-cloudfront

I'm trying to serve images uploaded with Paperclip through CloudFront for my Rails application. I've read a lot of posts and found that the following configuration should work:

```
has_attached_file :content, {
  :styles => {
    :medium=> "300x300>",
    :thumb=> "100x100#",
    :medium_square=> "700x500#",
    :facebook=> "1200x630>",
    :large=> "1920x"
  },
  :convert_options=> {
    :all=> '-strip -interlace Plane'
  },
  :default_url=> "/images/:style/missing.png",
  :path=> ":attachment/:id/:style.:extension"
  :url=> ':s3_alias_url',
  :s3_host_alias=> ENV['CLOUDFRONT_URL'],
  :s3_credentials=> {
    :bucket=> ENV['FOG_DIRECTORY'],
    :access_key_id=> ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    :secret_access_key=> ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
  }
}
```

However instead of sending the request to the CloudFront URL, it uses `':s3_alias_url'` as a string in the request path, like so:

```
http://application.com/pages/:asset_host?1446851994
```

I have tried using`':asset_host'` as an option as well, wtih the same result - it gets treated as a string.